# Converting Blender's UV vectors into 3D coordinates

Tags: python, 3d, blender, mesh, unwrap

I have converted a UV vector coordinates into 3D plane using Blender's Bmesh function. Using bmesh to create the newer mesh,

```
bm.faces.new((vert))
```

it creates faces that is undesirable, or more accurately, the edges and faces that are generated by the function are not as intended.

**Is there a way to allow no generation of edges that are more than the maximum connected distance of a mesh using bmesh?**

This [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJuVO.jpg) shows generation of both edges and faces on the left marked out in green, comparing with the seam that I have marked for UV unwrapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each face has a list of [edges](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMFace.edges), an edge can give you it's [length](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMEdge.calc_length) and if it's too long you can [remove](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMEdgeSeq.remove) it. Removing one of the edges will also delete the face.

```
f = bm.faces.new((vert))
for e in f.edges:
    if e.calc_length() > max_length:
        bm.edges.remove(e)
```

You can also get the distance between two vertices before using them to create a face `(v1.co-v2.co).length`, the trick is knowing which will be joined as edges and which will be diagonal across the face.